# how reindex and flush cache via code in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, reindex

How can reindex and then flush cache magento in code instead command line?

Answer (score 6):

**indexer:reindex**

**CMD:**

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex //for all
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product //for specific id
```

**Using DI**

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
*/
protected $_indexerFactory;

/**
* @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory
*/
protected $_indexerCollectionFactory;
    
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
){
    $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
    $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
}

// custom function for reindexing
public function reIndexing(){
    $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
    $allIds = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();

    foreach ($allIds as $id) {
        $indexer = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
        //$indexer->reindexRow($id); // or you can use reindexRow according to your need
        $indexer->reindexAll(); // this reindexes all
    }
}
```

**or by using object manager**

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$indexerCollectionFactory = $obj->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory");
$indexerFactory = $obj->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory");

// custom function for reindexing
public function reIndexing(){
    $indexerCollection = $indexerCollectionFactory->create();
    $allIds = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();

    foreach ($allIds as $id) {
        $indexer = $indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
        //$indexer->reindexRow($id); // or you can use reindexRow according to your need
        $indexer->reindexAll(); // this reindexes all
    }
}
```

**Cache flush/Clean:**

**CMD:**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Using DI:**

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
    $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
}


$types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
}
foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
    $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
}
```

**Using ObjectManager:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

try{
    $_cacheTypeList = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface');
    $_cacheFrontendPool = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool');
    $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
    }
    foreach ($_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
        $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $msg = 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();die();
}
```

for more details: [flush cache and reindexing programatically in magento 2](https://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/flush-cache-and-reindexing-programatically-in-magento-2/)

Comment: Indexer Types: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html#m2devgde-indexing-outofbox

Answer (score 4):

Every CLI command directly maps to a command class in the Magento source code. That makes it pretty easy to track down how Magento is doing it--just search for the command.

## cache:flush

`Magento\Backend\Console\Command\CacheFlushCommand` calls:

```
    $this->eventManager->dispatch('adminhtml_cache_flush_all');
    $this->cacheManager->flush($cacheTypes);
```

`$this->cacheManager` is `Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager`
`$this->eventManager` is `Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface`

...so you can inject those two classes into yours, and then call the methods.

## indexer:reindex

`Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand` calls equivalent to:

```
    $indexers = $this->indexerCollectionFactory->create()->getItems();
    foreach ($indexers as $indexer) {
        $indexer->reindexAll();
    }
```

...with `$this->indexerCollectionFactory` being an instance of `Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to flush the cache you should be able to do one of these

```
Mage::app()->cleanCache()
```

or

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

To programmatically reindex you need to initialize the index factory then iterate through each index.

```
/**
* @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
*/
protected $indexerFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory
) {
    $this->indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
}
```

Then you require a function to go through each indexID in the array

```
foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
    $indexer = $this->indexerFactory->create();
    $indexer->load($indexerId);
    $indexer->reindexAll();
}
```

There is a module there that may be of use if you don't want to create your own:  https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-product-indexer

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below code from magento root folder under any file name.

Ex - **yourmagentorootpath/filname.php**

```
<?php
    $command = 'php bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:flush';
    echo '<pre>' . shell_exec($command) . '</pre>';
?>
```